# c# method name expected INotifypropertyChanged

Tags: c#, inotifypropertychanged

I'm running into a problem. I'm a VB.net programmer and I'm trying to learn C#. On many VB projects that I have done I've always used a `viewModelBase` class where I can notify my properties over my project, when I try to convert the code from vb to C# I'm getting a `method name expected` on the line: `if (TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this)(propertyName) == null)`

```
[Conditional("DEBUG"), DebuggerStepThrough()]
    public void VerifyPropertyName(string propertyName)
    {
        if (TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this)(propertyName) == null)
        {
            string msg = "Invalid property name: " + propertyName;

            if (this.ThrowOnInvalidPropertyName)
            {
                throw new Exception(msg);
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Fail(msg);
            }
        }
    }
```

I really can't find any solution for this! Any help?

Thank you

Comment: The double parenthesis seem really off. You are only calling one function, so you should only have one set. Perhaps you meant to use a comma `GetProperties(this, propertyName)`?

Comment: @BradleyDotNET There's no overload of `TypeDescriptor.GetProperties()` that takes an `object` and a `string` assumably.

Comment: What did you *expect* `TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this)(propertyName)` to do?

Comment: Indexing is done with `[]` in C#, not `()` :-)

Comment: yeah i see what the error is, (this) has to be removed.. well like as i mention on vb that would be possible, doesnt look like it is in c# so the line would be: if (TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(propertyName) == null)

Comment: @Cameron: Yup, having checked the return type of `GetProperties`, that's what I reckon the mistake is too.

Comment: @Rui: No, that's *not* the problem. See my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you're just missing the fact that indexer syntax in C# is `[key]`. I suspect you want:

```
if (TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this)[propertyName] == null)
```

That's first calling the `GetProperties` method, to find the `PropertyDescriptorCollection` of all the properties of `this`... then it's using the [indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4htysy3.aspx) of `PropertyDescriptorCollection` to access a specific property by name.

Comment: I forgot VB uses () for array indexing. Good catch!

Comment: Yep, that's it the indexing in C# is done with [] and not ().. well i really have to put that in my head! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the "Find" function:

```
if (TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this).Find(propertyName, false) == null)
```

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.propertydescriptorcollection.find.aspx)

Note that this does a case-sensitive find.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but @Jon Skeet had a better one!

Comment: @Rui, No problem, I agree his approach is better, but found this approach in my research so I thought I would share! Glad you got your problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    [Conditional("DEBUG"), DebuggerStepThrough()]
    public void VerifyPropertyName(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyDescriptorCollection properties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this);
        var objValue = properties[propertyName].GetValue(this);
        if (objValue == null)
        {
            string msg = "Invalid property name: " + propertyName;

            if (this.ThrowOnInvalidPropertyName)
            {
                throw new Exception(msg);
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Fail(msg);
            }
        }
    }
```